# Kali Linux boots only when USB is plugged in

Tags: linux, boot

Hello I need a little help hopefully somebody can point me in the right direction.

I was having problems getting my macbook pro mid 2010 to boot from usb (to install Kali Linux), after selecting under REFind the installation usb a black screen appeared with the message “No bootable device”…

So I saw a post about changing the default menu string from syslinux.cfg file under the usb /EFI/BOOT/syslinux.cfg from something like vcmenu.c32 to just menu.c32 so after I did that I was able to boot from the usb in my mac…

Kali Linux installation went smoothly and when I tried to login (with a successful login) the system just crashed/freezed. After many unsuccessful start up of Kali Linux I tried to start up with the installation usb connected to the machine and I was surprised to see that I was able to log in and start the system and worked pretty good.

So my question is how can I start the system without the usb plugged into the Mac?.

Thanks and sorry for my bad english I’m from México

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how can I start the system without the USB plugged into the Mac?

If you don't want to run Kali from a Live USB, you need to install Kali on your hard drive.

When you first load Kali the first boot screen gives you several options to run the OS, to install Kali on your hard drive you need to select the 'Graphical Install' option. BEWARE, this option will erase your current operating system and hard drive and make Kali the only OS on the system, as a beginner this may be very, very difficult for you to navigate and use efficiently.

I would recommend that you research using either Dual Boot with OSX or use Kali within a virtual machine such as VMware or VirtualBox.

Comment: I did install Kali into the hard drive with the Graphical Install option, I created a special partition for Kali Linux. I am not booting a Live USB.